# find a random entry in a large JSON file

Tags: node.js, json

I want to get a random entry from a `JSON` object, which looks something like this:

```
{
    "one" : {
        "1" : [a, b, c],
        "2" : [d, e, f]
    },
    "two" : {
        "3" : [g, h, i],
        "4" : [j, k, l]
    }
}
```

How would I go about getting a random entry from one of the arrays?

Edit : I would want a random entry from an array (e.g. `[a, b, c]`), not from one of the nested *objects*

Comment: Please explain your question further.

Comment: Do you want the random item to be in `[a, b, c, ...]` or `[{1: ..., 2: ...}, ...]`?

Comment: So, you need one from: `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l]` list? Also, above `JSON` is invalid. Maybe it should be: `["a", "b", ...]`

Comment: Updated the question @NinoFiliu to clarify it. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you need to get `one` or `two` object, after that you need to get inner arrays. And finally, get one of the element from array. In case you need to do it many times, consider to create one array with all elements and get random value from it.

```js
    let json = {
            "one" : {
                "1" : ["a", "b", "c"],
                "2" : ["d", "e", "f"]
            },
            "two" : {
                "3" : ["g", "h", "i"],
                "4" : ["j", "k", "l"]
            }
        };
    let nextRandomMax = function(max) { 
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
    }
    let keys = Object.keys(json);
    let randomItem = json[keys[nextRandomMax(keys.length)]];
        
    // go further
    let itemKeys = Object.keys(randomItem);
    let randomTable = randomItem[itemKeys[nextRandomMax(itemKeys.length)]];

    let randomElement = randomTable[nextRandomMax( randomTable.length)]
    console.log(randomElement);
```

See:

- [JavaScript random() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)